# MIPS Assembly Language : Delay

Tags: mips

I want two numbers to be displayed one after another with a 3 seconds delay between them, How can that be done in MIPS ?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using MARS, `syscall 32` with put the main Java thread to sleep for a specified number of milliseconds.

[MARS syscalls](http://courses.missouristate.edu/KenVollmar/MARS/Help/SyscallHelp.html)

Comment: Thank you very much , I will try it as soon as possible .